# How to get the last X minutes of log messages

Tags: awk

Here is my log format:

```
127.0.0.1 user-identifier test [23/Jan/2018:16:45:22 -0700] [WARN ] message
127.0.0.1 user-identifier test [23/Jan/2018:16:55:23 -0700] [WARN ] message
127.0.0.1 user-identifier test [23/Jan/2018:17:00:24 -0700] [WARN ] message
```

And i use this to get last x min log:

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-60 min" "+[%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S")" -v d2="$(date "+[%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2' log.log
```

But, it seems not work because my log not starting with date. How it should be with my log format? Thanks

Comment: `awk` doesn't give you much in the realm of date management. If you were to store your dates as epoch seconds, it would be easier to compare them using `>` and `<`. Depending on your scale, you might want to look into solutions like Prometheus or the ELK stack.

Comment: Hi ghoti, thanks for the suggestion, i will look for it. i just want to make simple sript to check from the single file log for this case.

Comment: I would posit that "simple" won't be possible, with your source dates formatted like this. `23/01/2018` will always sort higher than `01/02/2018`. You'd need to compare epoch seconds or ISO8601 dates. You might be able to reformat your dates, but that's more than a one-liner of code. You might more easily write something to compare just the *time* and not take date into account.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution I can see to this would be to parse your log, live, adding a new date field which is more compatible with simple arithmetic comparisons.  For example, leave the following running all the time:

```
tail -0F /path/to/logfile | while read line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^([^[]+\[)([^]]+)(.*) ]]
  printf '%s %s%s%s\n' \
    $(date -j -f '%d/%b/%Y:%T %z' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" '+%s') \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done >> /path/to/epochlogfile
```

Note that I'm using BSD `date`, so I've got control over my input date format using `-f`. You appear to be using GNU coreutils' date command, so you'll need to figure out how to adapt the options to suit.  Perhaps something like:

```
tail -0F /path/to/logfile | while read line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^([^[]+\[)([^]]+)(.*) ]]
  printf '%s %s%s%s\n' \
    $(d="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; d="${d/:/ }"; d="${d//\// }"; date -d "$d" '+%s') \
    "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done >> /path/to/epochlog
```

If your `awk` is [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), you might opt to assume that `tail -F` will always output a log entry at the same time as is referenced by the timestamp. In this case, you don't need to *parse* the date, and you could simplify this with something like:

```
tail -0F /path/to/logfile | gawk '{print systime(),$0}' >> /path/to/epochlog
```

The `systime()` function is a gawk extension which returns the current epoch second. Just to reiterate, these times will reflect *when the log entry was reached the `tail` command* rather than *the time being logged by your application*.

Of course, even better than leaving it running would be to create your log using a searchable date in the first place. You haven't said what's creating this log, so I can't make any specific suggestions in that area.

Once you've got your replacement log file, you can search with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $(uname -s) in
  Linux)        date_opts=( --date="-60 min" ) ;;
  *BSD|Darwin)  date_opts=( -v-60M ) ;;
  *) echo "No."; exit 1 ;;
esac

start=$(date "${date_opts[@]}" '+%s')

awk -v start="$start" '$1 > start' /path/to/epochlogfile
```

I skipped your `d2` date condition because, well, it's now. And there's no reason this search script needs to be bash, it could be POSIX easily enough. I'm just lazy. By now you probably understand this enough to add it again if it's important to you.

Disclaimer: Untested. YMMV. May contain nuts.

Comment: I think you'll need `stdbuf -oL tail | while read ...` (or something comparable on BSD ;) ) Besides that, wouldn't `stdbuf -oL tail | awk` being the better alternative compared to a bash `while read` loop?

Comment: Nice approach, but FWIW, in GNU Awk, you could simplify things a little bit with [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)..

Comment: @hek2mgl - Heh, actually `stdbuf` has been in FreeBSD since 2013. But it's not in macOS or Solaris, so I wouldn't recommend it for portability. And as far as I'm aware, `tail` has always either provided unbuffered output or flushed its buffer at every newline. Awk has `fflush()` to clear its *output* buffer, but it doesn't do anything to its input. What *would* be a concern is if you were running this through `grep`, which might want a `--line-buffered` option to be part of a successful pipeline.

Comment: @randomir, yes indeed, though additional complexity would be required to parse existing dates and handle timezones. Most of my work is done in FreeBSD though, so I tend to aim for more platform-agnostic solutions. That said, I would LOVE to see [strptime() in gawk](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2014-08/msg00024.html). :-)

Comment: @ghoti Looks like you are right and you don't need `stdbuf` in combination with `tail`. I'm confused now. I'm pretty sure that "there was something".. Anyhow, good answer! PS: I second the request for `strptime()` in gawk!

Comment: @ghoti, I agree, `strptime()` would be great to have in gawk.

Comment: @randomir, after thinking about this a bit, I've added a simple gawk option that assumes rapid log delivery rather than parsing the date. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the script in the same TZ as whatevers producing the logs then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[ /:]+" }
{
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$5)+2)/3
    time  = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", $6, mthNr, $4, $7, $8, $9)
}
time > tgt
```

which will work with any `awk` and you'd execute as:

```
awk -v tgt="$(date --date='-60 min' +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')" -f tst.awk
```

using the version of `date` you're already using that supports those arguments.